# How to Find Twitter Accounts by Location?

Tags: twitter, search, geolocation

I've met some wonderful people on Twitter and would like to meet more people from different places; it's great to read local tweets from all over.

I'd like to follow some non-celebrities from different parts of the country/world but the only online services I've found so far to find Tweeters based on location only show those with high follower counts.  I'd like to find "regular" people, people with lower follow counts but who are interesting.

Is there any service or way on Twitter to read Tweets from specific locations or find Twitter accounts in regions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Streamd.in](http://streamd.in/):

> Twitter client that connects you with other Twitter users in your local city or town.

In the picture below you can see it is paired with Google Maps.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Happn.in](http://happn.in/):

> Happn.in gives Twitter a local focus. For each Happn.in city, there is a current list of Local Twitter Trends

Also, take a look at Mashable's [article](http://mashable.com/2009/06/08/twitter-local-2/) on finding local Twitter users.